# Free Body diagram force question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, free-body-diagram

[image]

Here is a semicircular track and the ring of mass $m$ sliding on it. The ring is attached to spring of force constant $k$ and the elongation $x$ at that point.I just wanted to know that just as I release the ring, from the location on track which is shown in figure, would the total force in the Y direction (also the direction of normal contact force) be zero? And if it is then is it due to the face that just as I release the ring, the centripetal acceleration for be zero as the ring would not have acquired any velocity just after the release?

Comment: If the net force in Y direction be zero, then the ring won't move **on** the circle and will lose the contact.

Comment: @lucas  
I am talking about the moment just after I release, meaning no acceleration or complete balance of forces, in the direction just after the release.

Comment: If the ring be in equilibrium just after the release, then it will be in equilibrium for ever.

Comment: In other words, if the force in the Y direction were zero, the acceleration will be in the direction of the spring.  The ring will not stay on the circle.